# Angular Guard doesnt work with rxjs filter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

iam trying to use RouteGuard in my app to prevent unauthorized users from accessing it. My can activate method in Guard looks like this:

```
canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
  return this.statusService.appStatus.pipe(filter(status=>{
    return status.selectedAgency!=null;
  }),map(status=>{
       console.log(status)
    if(status.selectedAgency.allowPreEdit){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }))
}
```

Iam trying to filter default value from appStatus observable, because its null for selectedAgency. Later the agency is initialized from home component via changeSelectedAgency method. The problem is that it doesnt work - if i use filter method, guard just receives nothing - even the console.log in map method doesnt occur. Any ideas what am i doing wrong? Why it doesnt wait for result? Init Agency just doesnt occur, iam left on a blank screen with no error in console. There must be some problem with the guard - it doesnt let the agency init, but i dont know why. Any ideas.
StatusService looks like this:

```
export class StatusService {
  private statusSubj= new BehaviorSubject<AppStatus>({selectedMonth:new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()),selectedAgency:null});


  get appStatus(){
    return this.statusSubj.asObservable();
  }

  changeSelectedAgency(selectedAgency:Agency){
    console.log("changeagency");
    this.appStatus.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(currentStatus=>{
      this.statusSubj.next({...currentStatus,selectedAgency:selectedAgency})
    })
  }

 ...
}


export class HomeComponent{
  user$:Observable<User>;
  agencies:Agency[]=[];
  selectedAgency:Agency=null;
  commonLoaded=false;

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private userService:UserService, private planService:PlanService, private statusService:StatusService, private commonService:CommonService) {
    this.user$=this.userService.currentUser;
    forkJoin([this.planService.getAgencies(new Date()),this.commonService.loadTypes()]).subscribe(data=>{
      this.initAgencies(data[0]);
      console.log(data);
      this.commonLoaded=true;
    })
  }

  private initAgencies(agList:Agency[]){
    this.agencies=agList;
    console.log("init");
    this.statusService.changeSelectedAgency(agList[0]);
    this.selectedAgency=agList[0];
  }
```

home component html:

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="commonLoaded">
  ...
      <div class="controls-toolbar" *ngIf="agencies.length>0" fxLayoutGap="30px" fxLayoutAlign="left center">
        <app-monthpicker></app-monthpicker>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="no-padding no-underline">
          <mat-label>Vybraná činnost</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedAgency" (ngModelChange)="changeAgency($event)" [compareWith]="compareAgencies">
            <mat-option [value]="agency"  *ngFor="let agency of agencies">Činnost č. {{agency.agNum}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="workplace-info" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="10px"><mat-icon>home</mat-icon><p>{{selectedAgency.wpDesc}}</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-container" *ngIf="selectedAgency">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</ng-container>
```

And finally routes:

```
   const routes: Routes = [
      {path:"",component:HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        children:[
          {path:'',redirectTo:"timesheet",pathMatch:"full"},
          {path:'timesheet',component:TimesheetComponent},
          ...
          {path:"shiftRecords",component:ShiftRecordsComponent, canActivate:[PreEditGuard]},
          {path:'passchange',component:PassChangeComponent}
        ]},
      {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
      {path:"**",redirectTo:''}
```

Comment: Well `selectedAgency` is explicitely set to `null` in `statusSubj`, but you have a filter that discards it: `selectedAgency!=null`, so it is discarded and `map` never happens.

Comment: The observable has to complete. Yours doesn't. Maybe add the first() or take(1) operator?

Comment: its initiatet later via initAgency from another component. But all this doesnt occur, guard somehow prevents it, but i have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedAgency:null` in the `BehaviorSubject` is the problem here.

Because of this, `filter` gives you an empty observable, so `map` doesn't run. This leads to `canActivate` returning observable with falsy value, so routing is prevented and `HomeComponent` is not initialised, so, the constructor doesn't run and `initAgencies` is not called.

So, it is kind of a deadlock situation, `canActivate` depends on **component initialisation** (to call `initAgencies` and set `selectedAgency` ) but **component initialisation** depends  on `canActivate` (to return true, so that routing and initialisation can take place).

So, you can provide some proper default value to `selectedAgency` or tweak your logic in some other way.

Comment: Ah, i thought that filter will not emit any value that doesnt meet the condition, its weird behaviour that it returns empty observable and completes it. Is there any other rxjs operator i can use for this? I thought that it will not emit default value so it will wait for value that is not null

Comment: I don't think any operator can help because the problem is in the logic. If you are checking for selectedAgency!=null, you'll not want it to proceed with null value, so setting some default value for selectedAgency can help otherwise you'll have to tweak your logic in some other way. Plus, if you think you can use some operator that'll wait, that also not gonna work because it will keep waiting forever if routing doesn't happen and HomeCompnent is not initialised.

Comment: I dont quite understand why HomeComponent doesnt initialize - on home component, there is only user guard and it works ok. The problem is in PreEditGuard, but thats on child route "shiftRecords", i thought that it will load HomeComponent, and then the PreEditGuard kicks in... So the selected agency would be already initialized. I didnt know that guard on childRoute blocks even the parent route. So there isnt any walkaround?